# How to add data(dict) to a specific fieldname(key) on a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion I'll explain what the program is for. It's to keep track of a users new weight record. This file will only update when they have exceeded their previous weight record with a timestamp. I want the user to be able to see a time line of their progress for each lift using the timestamp. This is why i was using lift['key']={data:dict} So that they can reference each lift type and query the date for example lift['snatch']['5/25'] this will tell them what they maxed that day. But i can't seem to be able to write this to a csv file properly. Thank you for you time! Happy friday!

I've been researching for days and can't seem to figure out how to add data to a specific **Fieldname** which is a the highest level key in my dict.

The data i want to add is a dict in it's own.

How I vision it to look like in the CSV file:

```
snatch         <>     squat          <>    jerk
10/25:150lbs   <>     10/25:200lbs   <>    10/25:0lbs
```

So this is how it would look like when they created the file. How am I able to update just one field.

Say the user only squatted that day and wants to **Append** data to that **Field**.

What I have so far:

```
import time
import csv
lifts={}
csv_columns = ['snatch','squat','jerk']
creation = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.localtime())

lifts['snatch']={creation:'150lbs'}
lifts['squat']={creation:'200lbs'}
lifts['jerk']={creation:'0lbs'}

try:
  with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csvDictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in lifts:
      writer.writerow(lifts)
    except IOError as (errno, sterror):
      print("Error")
    return
```

->One of my issues is that when it writers to the csv file it writes it over three times. Not quite sure why. It's the format I want but it's there three times.

-> I also want to implement this next code and write to the specific column, when i do so it writes null or blanks in the other columns.

```
lifts['jerk'].update({time.strftime('%M:%S', time.localtime() : '160lbs'})
```

Then out putting

```
snatch         <>     squat          <>    jerk
10/25:150lbs   <>     10/25:200lbs   <>    10/25:0lbs    10/26:160lbs
```

Sorry I'm new to python and not quit sure how to use this editor i want that result to land under the `{10/25:0lbs}` Just like it would show in excel.

Comment: Are you using the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: The structure of your data is poor.  You should have a separate column for date and probably would be better to have a separate row for each exercise, such that your columns would be like `date,exercise,weight`.  Then you would be able to easily get more granular with extra columns like `reps,sets,cc_of_steroids`.

Comment: If the items in a row of your file are not necessarily related to each other, it might make sense to organize the file differently. For instance, you could make the type of the lift (snatch, squat or jerk) a value in a field, rather than separate fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply's and advice!
Could you give me an example? I've only been programing for a week so im not aware of any other structure. Yes I'm using csv in order to save it to a excel document. As for for I'm using this format is to be able to reference by date how much they lifted,

For example. 'lifts['jerk']['5/28']' will give the user the max weight they lifted that day. I know that my timestamp is in minutes and seconds that's to make sure it's working ill change the format later.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to keep track of what's going on here: `lifts` is a dictionary with strings for keys ("snatch", "squat", "jerk") and whose values are also dictionaries. This second level of dictionaries has timestamp strings for keys and strings as values.

I suspect that when you want to update the `lifts['jerk']` dictionary, you don't use the same key (timestamp) as the existing entry.

It doesn't seem like you need a dictionary for the second level; consider using a list instead, but if you must, you can access like so: `lifts['jerk'][lifts['jerk'].keys()[0]]` which is rather hamfisted - again, consider either using a different data type for the values of your `lifts` dictionary or use keys that are easier to reference than timestamps.

EDIT: You could do something like `lifts['jerk'] = {'timestamp':creation,'weight':'165lbs'}` which requires some restructuring of your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm only using creation once during the file creation function in my program. The reason I wanted to use dicts is to be able to reference how much the user lifted in that date.

Won't using your edited example not link the date to the weight they lifted?

Comment: It depends on how you look at your data: Personally, I would invert your data and store the timestamp at the top level with the different lift types below it: `lifts['10/19']['jerk']` or something, which would give you a dictionary that looks like `lifts = {'10/19':{'squat':'130lb', 'snatch':'100lb'}}`. How to correlate the date with the data is a matter of choice.

Comment: Thank you again for you advice! I think this would defeat my purpose. I guess I should explain my program. It keeps track of personal records. So If the user broke a record on squats today then he can update his file. 

But with your method, I belief that if he didn't squat that day and he maxed his jerk when he is going to write to the file it would add a null which is the issue im having now to that row. So if i query my data for the latest update or a timeline it would display a bunch of 0s. Is there a way around this? Thank you for your time again!

Comment: ok - so each element in the second-tier dictionary is max for that day? that's fine, but now I'm unsure of what your problem is. If you only want to show one entry of that dictionary (`{'10/19':'0lbs','10/20':'160lbs'}` has 2 entries) you have to come up with some method of choosing one of them.